# How can I use a variable used in PHP Class Function into another file?

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch some variables into another file from a PHP class and could not quiet figure out the way to do it.

I am attaching a piece of dummy code which shows what exactly I am trying to do

Suppose there is a PHP class named Products.php in which there is a function getProducts() which have a variable $product_name

```
public function getProducts() { 
       $product_name = "Some name";  
  }
```

Now I want this variable $product_name to be used in a seperate file which is named as products.php. How can i use it there? I made an instance of the class like

```
$products = new Products($connection);
```

The above is just an example so please don't mind any other mistakes made, I just want to know how can i access that variable into another file!

Thanks for all the helps in advance.

Comment: Syntax aside, this doesn't make sense from the OOP point of view. If you have a class, you probably want to use class properties, not expose internal local variables.

Comment: `$products->product_name` ? Well, that works only of `$product_name` is a public property of `Products` class

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return` in the function and include the PHP file with the function in your file. The result looks somewhat like this:

file1.php

```
public function getProducts() { 
   $product_name = "Some name";  
   return $product_name;
}
```

file2.php

```
include 'file1.php';
$product_name = getProducts();
```

Please keep in mind that PHP code written in this way is bad style. Here are some explanations on how PHP should be written: https://www.phptherightway.com/